# Transferring Data Between Workbooks Based on a Value in a Specific Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have created a form in Excel that moves information entered in the form to the adjacent sheet in the same workbook as well as my agents workbook at a different file path. That piece of the puzzle is set squarely in place! Works like a charm!

From here I am going to create two additional workbooks identical to the first agent (3 agents in all) where the information will also filter simultaneously.

What I can't figure out is how to further detail the transfer by only having the information go to one workbook if the agents name is listed in a specific column.

In my case, my agents name is in **Column D**.  When I hit transmit, I would like to know if my macro will recognize the name entered in that specific cell and route it to that specific agents workbook as opposed to all 3 agents?

I know this is possible, but my little pea brain won't allow me access to anymore of my brain cells!  I am new to writing in VBA, so I may be missing a lot. Any help would be appreciated.  The current code I have in place is below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim DateReceived As Date
Dim CustomerName As String
Dim AcctNumber As Single
Dim AssignedAgent As String
Dim DisputeCode As Single
Dim ProjRespDate As Date
Dim DocUploadDate As Date
Dim DirectMailForm As Workbook

Worksheets("Form").Select
DateReceived = Range("G3")
CustomerName = Range("G4")
AcctNumber = Range("G5")
AssignedAgent = Range("G6")
DisputeCode = Range("G7")
ProjRespDate = Range("G8")
DocUploadDate = Range("G9")

Worksheets("Data").Select
Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Data").Range("A1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = DateReceived
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = CustomerName
.Offset(RowCount, 2) = AcctNumber
.Offset(RowCount, 3) = AssignedAgent
.Offset(RowCount, 4) = DisputeCode
.Offset(RowCount, 5) = ProjRespDate
.Offset(RowCount, 6) = DocUploadDate

End With

Worksheets("Form").Select
Worksheets("Form").Range("G3").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Range("G3:G9").ClearContents

Set DisputeForm = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\klx380\Documents\Consolidated_Dispute_Tracker_2014.xls")
Worksheets("Mail").Select
Worksheets("Mail").Range("A1").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("Mail").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Mail").Range("A1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = DateReceived
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = CustomerName
.Offset(RowCount, 2) = AcctNumber
.Offset(RowCount, 3) = AssignedAgent
.Offset(RowCount, 4) = DisputeCode
.Offset(RowCount, 5) = ProjRespDate
.Offset(RowCount, 6) = DocUploadDate

End With

DisputeForm.Save
DisputeForm.Close


End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If [G9].Value <> "" Then
  CommandButton1.Enabled = True
Else: CommandButton1.Enabled = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you put a forumla in a cell which allows you to check whether to copy to the other workbook? If you can then you could just copy if that cell had a value of TRUE.